# Is there a way to add a jQuery string inside of a Google Sheet?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

So imagine I have a string,

```
var greet = "hi"
```

And I want to put it in the next available row in a Google Sheet, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in Google Apps Script. Google Apps Script is a cloud-based JavaScript platform that lets you integrate with and automate tasks across Google products.

To go to Google Apps Script

1. Go to Extensions -> Apps Script.
2. Remove the code in Code.gs file
3. Paste the code below.
4. Run and authorize

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
//this code will insert hi to the next available row of active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var greet = "hi"
  sheet.appendRow([greet])
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

*Note: If Google Apps Script is not an option for you, you have to use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)*

### References:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)